# Extracting Hyperlink Text from <a> tag using selenium on Python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I am currently trying to pull all the,  elements using tag name in selenium, but then when I try to iterate through the list of all  elements and use get_attribute('text') or ('innerHTML') to get the text attribute, I am left with a list full of "None".

I am checked that the list of  elements wasn't also full of none since I verified to see if it had any value using print statements but I'm unsure what could be the problem now. I tried multiple different operators I saw being used by others such as only extracting the active tags and using .text() instead of get_attribute to extract the text, but looking further into it, that also wouldnt work since once selenium finds the element, its stored as a hash or something. I am going to put my code and output underneath.

```py
    from selenium import webdriver
    from selenium.webdriver import Firefox
    from selenium.webdriver.firefox.service import Service
    from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
    from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select
    from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
    import time

    # User-defined list of items
    items = ['water', 'orange juice', 'soda']

    # Start the browser session
    driver_path = r"C:\\VSCode\geckodriver.exe"
    service = Service(executable_path='C:\\VSCode\\geckodriver.exe')
    driver = Firefox(service=service).driver.get("https://bangyourbuck.com/")

    # Iterate through each item in the list
    for item in items:
    # Find the search bar and enter the item name
        search_bar = driver.find_element("xpath", '//div[@class="col-12 col-md-12 mb-2 mb-md-0"]//input[@placeholder="Search for anything (e.g. rice)..."]')
        search_bar.send_keys(str(item))

    # Sort by price per fl oz
    sort_button = driver.find_element(By.NAME, 'desired_units')
    select = Select(sort_button)
    sort_by_ppf = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'option[value=Fluid_Ounce]')
    sort_by_ppf.click()
    calculateButton = driver.find_element(By.NAME, 'submitButton')
    calculateButton.click()
    time.sleep(1)

    # Get the top 5 result
    linkPath = driver.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, 'a')[10:15]
    namePath = driver.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "a")
    pricePath = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, 'card-text')
    Links = []
    Names = []

    Links = [Links.append(link.get_attribute('href')) for link in linkPath]
    Names = [Names.append(name.get_attribute('text')for name in namePath]
    print(namePath)
    print(Names)

    driver.get('https://bangyourbuck.com/')
    search_bar.clear()

    # Close the browser session
    driver.quit()
```

Output:

```
`[<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="01696fd6-d458-4960-9feb-25c558d5cb59", element="eafb8305-0f91-48b6-84c7-5ffab4a91499")>, <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="01696fd6-d458-4960-9feb-25c558d5cb59", element="3ff0fee1-007f-4ba1-a1ae-f7ab943206cc")>, <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="01696fd6-d458-4960-9feb-25c558d5cb59", element="8ad761e1-50de-4c00-9165-3ea8cf6f9650")>, <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="01696fd6-d458-4960-9feb-25c558d5cb59", element="4996414f-1c03-48ed-bb27-22eb01f0b01a")>, <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="01696fd6-d458-4960-9feb-25c558d5cb59", element="1dfa5113-9c3a-40b7-b11f-d671f43b381d")>, <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="01696fd6-d458-4960-9feb-25c558d5cb59", element="905b423f-8684-48d3-b8e8-2b6da169b6f8")>, <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="01696fd6-d458-4960-9feb-25c558d5cb59", element="058fb95e-c0ea-4e83-91ba-38e303149793")>, <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="01696fd6-d458-4960-9feb-25c558d5cb59", element="adc37497-6a3b-4419-a3bf-56bfe5ea8665")>, <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="01696fd6-d458-4960-9feb-25c558d5cb59", element="d468ce14-519c-4d0b-be42-649d22cb528f")>, <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="01696fd6-d458-4960-9feb-25c558d5cb59", element="700e553e-3a53-483a-adf2-b64fa1fb373b")>, <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="01696fd6-d458-4960-9feb-25c558d5cb59", element="083da717-e308-4b57-b5c6-e4a5f360380d")>, <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="01696fd6-d458-4960-9feb-25c558d5cb59", element="457327cb-202a-4f86-8eec-5a0d3dd5924e")>, <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="01696fd6-d458-4960-9feb-25c558d5cb59", element="0164df36-f6cb-4aae-908f-e199452b28f2")>, <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="01696fd6-d458-4960-9feb-25c558d5cb59", element="d412262c-776d-421d-adad-3f4d18772efe")>, <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="01696fd6-d458-4960-9feb-25c558d5cb59", element="e4191100-89d6-4da5-9e8d-36423379c9d5")>, <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="01696fd6-d458-4960-9feb-25c558d5cb59", element="eca73863-ac7d-48ae-832d-383d11d4d58c")>, <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="01696fd6-d458-4960-9feb-25c558d5cb59", element="85f9f826-fdcc-49a8-aacc-cf4c779bb836")>, <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="01696fd6-d458-4960-9feb-25c558d5cb59", element="c4007323-63be-499e-b908-4b191056ff99")>, <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="01696fd6-d458-4960-9feb-25c558d5cb59", element="786e2833-aea0-4994-9c97-d1548692296b")>, <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="01696fd6-d458-4960-9feb-25c558d5cb59", element="2cb107e6-abac-47e8-8815-2b4348d94878")>, <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="01696fd6-d458-4960-9feb-25c558d5cb59", element="eaa00e76-f6a1-4367-81bd-4f738560deb7")>, <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="01696fd6-d458-4960-9feb-25c558d5cb59", element="93e415ea-a7eb-4596-90af-915cc311d157")>, <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="01696fd6-d458-4960-9feb-25c558d5cb59", element="2cb66695-73a1-4852-9126-9ebb58e063f6")>, <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="01696fd6-d458-4960-9feb-25c558d5cb59", element="120b5e06-f51a-4ceb-8833-908e9b26eb7b")>, <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="01696fd6-d458-4960-9feb-25c558d5cb59", element="d24ad6d4-1209-4d16-9b8c-e677f4a9a318")>, <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="01696fd6-d458-4960-9feb-25c558d5cb59", element="f692589c-1975-4abc-9566-20305c9e9033")>, <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="01696fd6-d458-4960-9feb-25c558d5cb59", element="f55360a0-45bd-4979-b174-e9836e780ef1")>, <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="01696fd6-d458-4960-9feb-25c558d5cb59", element="60e7f725-7bb7-48b0-9aac-cc193cf2907b")>, <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="01696fd6-d458-4960-9feb-25c558d5cb59", element="0118032f-e96b-42a4-9401-187bbd4a80bf")>, <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="01696fd6-d458-4960-9feb-25c558d5cb59", element="dde2e741-9a70-487a-8300-5ad113649d1d")>, <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="01696fd6-d458-4960-9feb-25c558d5cb59", element="c3002259-2084-4a9c-85dc-9ff9d795b6cf")>, <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="01696fd6-d458-4960-9feb-25c558d5cb59", element="2f99f800-32b6-4486-bb32-84149f3cd498")>, <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="01696fd6-d458-4960-9feb-25c558d5cb59", element="62f8e7cf-57ca-447f-9618-193537517a60")>, <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="01696fd6-d458-4960-9feb-25c558d5cb59", element="cdaebb2c-a1e4-4cec-841f-836ca0f3818b")>, <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="01696fd6-d458-4960-9feb-25c558d5cb59", element="6efdafb2-2d55-4fa2-9cb7-8b35e0ce5c73")>, <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="01696fd6-d458-4960-9feb-25c558d5cb59", element="4e1aac45-3536-4f0d-a4e7-abffb0d4c692")>, <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="01696fd6-d458-4960-9feb-25c558d5cb59", element="29b57288-879b-4647-8121-c85c2f4f7bac")>, <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="01696fd6-d458-4960-9feb-25c558d5cb59", element="10bb6ed3-e2d8-471b-b3c4-58667a01b564")>, <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="01696fd6-d458-4960-9feb-25c558d5cb59", element="d33c74a2-1dc2-441d-bad6-0a24dc517f32")>, <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="01696fd6-d458-4960-9feb-25c558d5cb59", element="18ea9912-dc05-46dd-ae1a-c8af27a5c9d6")>, <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="01696fd6-d458-4960-9feb-25c558d5cb59", element="42e86568-59e0-4e63-8f2c-2f18e4573930")>, <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="01696fd6-d458-4960-9feb-25c558d5cb59", element="a46dd8b9-8042-42a2-bae9-71ba15d192ef")>, <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="01696fd6-d458-4960-9feb-25c558d5cb59", element="f5233783-503c-4ff1-a00e-cfa92a6af3b0")>, <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="01696fd6-d458-4960-9feb-25c558d5cb59", element="141e3d97-b484-496e-a15f-9276aa1893d3")>, <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="01696fd6-d458-4960-9feb-25c558d5cb59", element="5f1e5b00-cc14-48a4-9d83-4ba7c859c966")>, <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="01696fd6-d458-4960-9feb-25c558d5cb59", element="d5f8a1b6-b141-4f83-9029-ccb73029797b")>, <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="01696fd6-d458-4960-9feb-25c558d5cb59", element="d2286e2e-5f59-452f-b537-d8d3f0474a20")>, <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="01696fd6-d458-4960-9feb-25c558d5cb59", element="b0cf8160-a8f8-408c-8171-3400f076237e")>, <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="01696fd6-d458-4960-9feb-25c558d5cb59", element="9a349ff0-7eb9-45f7-8f14-06c1a6ffb8eb")>, <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="01696fd6-d458-4960-9feb-25c558d5cb59", element="19064dbc-c549-4efc-90c4-5a0f316360c8")>, <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="01696fd6-d458-4960-9feb-25c558d5cb59", element="f6908940-f65b-4a63-aeb8-6693bbc6ac17")>, <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="01696fd6-d458-4960-9feb-25c558d5cb59", element="38a22ac4-48f6-44cb-9b09-289d53e4d855")>, <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="01696fd6-d458-4960-9feb-25c558d5cb59", element="01998626-cedc-448b-a633-4fc7ccd7cd7e")>, <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="01696fd6-d458-4960-9feb-25c558d5cb59", element="88d9dc52-c004-433c-bc0c-b927b506e4ed")>, <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="01696fd6-d458-4960-9feb-25c558d5cb59", element="3b6ce269-789d-4e99-81c8-dfc7e18e8cea")>, <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="01696fd6-d458-4960-9feb-25c558d5cb59", element="88de2123-4659-46e6-a3db-8a50114d1cb6")>, <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="01696fd6-d458-4960-9feb-25c558d5cb59", element="3a1216e5-0856-49b8-89d9-13ff9cecfde5")>, <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="01696fd6-d458-4960-9feb-25c558d5cb59", element="f5ebcff6-08dc-410d-9fcd-53514b95f83b")>, <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="01696fd6-d458-4960-9feb-25c558d5cb59", element="85ea8ce9-a902-4f7d-977f-f20c207fb6dd")>, <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="01696fd6-d458-4960-9feb-25c558d5cb59", element="889f5af9-1f04-4801-8a4d-e4c77a1299fa")>, <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="01696fd6-d458-4960-9feb-25c558d5cb59", element="ba61649a-d7f9-4830-974e-25bbf96fae03")>, <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="01696fd6-d458-4960-9feb-25c558d5cb59", element="1da03f83-729e-4b42-8ec1-68fa9eeb0145")>, <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="01696fd6-d458-4960-9feb-25c558d5cb59", element="1884200b-7ecc-41e2-981b-daf26251a64f")>, <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="01696fd6-d458-4960-9feb-25c558d5cb59", element="6ea6ef65-8f0b-4a8b-a9a7-b5b17678ec58")>, <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="01696fd6-d458-4960-9feb-25c558d5cb59", element="78404bb1-6ce2-4f97-8518-154e4995f8cd")>, <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="01696fd6-d458-4960-9feb-25c558d5cb59", element="558077dc-86da-4212-b7c5-2559b11f1b90")>, <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="01696fd6-d458-4960-9feb-25c558d5cb59", element="7c32580e-6dc7-4fba-9158-9cca7285833d")>, <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="01696fd6-d458-4960-9feb-25c558d5cb59", element="c1fd875b-c352-461b-980e-22eaea077351")>, <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="01696fd6-d458-4960-9feb-25c558d5cb59", element="18682551-2d31-483d-89bf-fb6588bb0583")>, <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="01696fd6-d458-4960-9feb-25c558d5cb59", element="27be5406-20ba-4488-bfbe-582f1db21cbc")>, <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="01696fd6-d458-4960-9feb-25c558d5cb59", element="79dbf5d1-6e9b-499b-ba19-ccb56efa9973")>, <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="01696fd6-d458-4960-9feb-25c558d5cb59", element="f8d0e8dc-4529-4474-8346-26fb9c235409")>, <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="01696fd6-d458-4960-9feb-25c558d5cb59", element="ed582186-68f5-4caa-99ba-53be1ab059bd")>, <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="01696fd6-d458-4960-9feb-25c558d5cb59", element="c8af9dfb-5156-45f6-9bc4-1fc6d2241590")>, <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="01696fd6-d458-4960-9feb-25c558d5cb59", element="851e9e61-fa35-4fe1-a309-fa7c103d103e")>, <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="01696fd6-d458-4960-9feb-25c558d5cb59", element="c22002aa-6da1-4ef4-8672-338007ce3971")>, <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="01696fd6-d458-4960-9feb-25c558d5cb59", element="98ec497e-1a4c-49b1-915b-d34b89545a28")>, <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="01696fd6-d458-4960-9feb-25c558d5cb59", element="2a1e4595-594f-4305-9b6d-062503694b69")>, <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="01696fd6-d458-4960-9feb-25c558d5cb59", element="86e47638-bf6f-4b61-b5a3-fec84b5630be")>, <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="01696fd6-d458-4960-9feb-25c558d5cb59", element="7f38f201-1be6-42d2-b0c4-a6887b113430")>, <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="01696fd6-d458-4960-9feb-25c558d5cb59", element="4a488d20-6480-418b-b1e5-3368d378b8d5")>, <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="01696fd6-d458-4960-9feb-25c558d5cb59", element="2926f797-f928-45c2-9328-e6cc02cb62b8")>, <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="01696fd6-d458-4960-9feb-25c558d5cb59", element="1473983c-1cec-4964-9fb2-70a0e5c4f8af")>, <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="01696fd6-d458-4960-9feb-25c558d5cb59", element="68fb8bb4-d181-42d7-9505-e10b7bfa4527")>, <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="01696fd6-d458-4960-9feb-25c558d5cb59", element="54424d99-8857-4c0e-8a44-263d852910f7")>, <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="01696fd6-d458-4960-9feb-25c558d5cb59", element="31e9b4c4-37ae-42da-8033-d6b1b7744697")>, <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="01696fd6-d458-4960-9feb-25c558d5cb59", element="d903eb35-f41d-4c9a-a5c3-5db6af75900c")>, <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="01696fd6-d458-4960-9feb-25c558d5cb59", element="a6c27c94-76e3-494c-8261-2c47fc45eab6")>, <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="01696fd6-d458-4960-9feb-25c558d5cb59", element="c8c103c7-da51-4bdb-8711-00b1dbc3f7c5")>, <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="01696fd6-d458-4960-9feb-25c558d5cb59", element="2e985e74-fc03-4e5c-8ab2-d2fdade38227")>, <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="01696fd6-d458-4960-9feb-25c558d5cb59", element="9248059a-ce49-4e23-a0bf-ae9e46448d4c")>, <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="01696fd6-d458-4960-9feb-25c558d5cb59", element="6a9cf622-dfd1-468f-a5eb-6aadf7d69a67")>, <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="01696fd6-d458-4960-9feb-25c558d5cb59", element="d6a4a1de-2705-4195-8a47-747c382b3d6f")>, <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="01696fd6-d458-4960-9feb-25c558d5cb59", element="1670002e-cb9c-428e-8439-0c5e88a2baab")>, <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="01696fd6-d458-4960-9feb-25c558d5cb59", element="a617a387-d626-4085-b3a7-97c7d041365b")>]
[None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None]`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you don't wait for element to be rendered and as a name you print namePath, which is in your case is `WebElement`.

Keep it simple. You products have unique class `card-body`.

To get first 5 products, you need just to wait for presence of all cards, loop through first one and get it inner elements that corresponding needed card fields.

```py
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

#your code 

cards = wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'card-body')))
Links = []
Names = []
Prices = []

for i in range(5):
    link = cards[i].find_element(By.TAG_NAME, 'a').get_attribute('href')
    name = cards[i].find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'card-title').get_attribute('innerText')
    price = cards[i].find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'black-link').get_attribute('innerText')
    Links.append(link)
    Names.append(name)
    Prices.append(price)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I want to understand what I did wrong, can you please explain what I did wrong briefly? was it that I needed to first find all the elements that had text boxes, then use those elements to find the elements within the element that held all of the information I originally needed? and then does getting that attribute on the same line affect it in any way? other than that, I get it. I genuienly do appreciate your help!

Comment: @AlexanderIglesias Main issue there was that you haven't waited for elements to be rendered. Implicit wait for 1 seconds doesn't guarantee that needed element / attribute of needed element is rendered after click. So you received array of Nones - elements were appeared, but probably their attributes weren't rendered.

Also, relaying on indexes from root [10:15] is not good practice. Amount of a can change and you would recieve wrong elements. Getting root container of your links is better (you can be sure that you get needed nested link inside container)

Comment: Thanks! Appreciate it a lot. This was my first time trying to work with front end so I don't know best practices but this really helped me learn a lot. I had tried putting the implicit wait for 10 seconds to make sure they were rendered before hand though, so I'm not sure If that changes anything, but it works now, so I'll just use that syntax for finding an element then getting its attribute on the same line as well as using explicit waits, and the root container method makes sense now. Thanks again!!!